# "How to determine..." vs "How can I determine..."

Tags: grammar, questions

> How to determine if my roulette wins were due to luck or due to skill?

Someone told me that question above is ungrammatical and should be changed to:

> How can I determine if my roulette wins were due to luck or due to skill?

Is my original sentence incorrect? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were correct, starting a sentence with *"How to"* is invalid in English.

*"How to"* is a fragment of a complete sentence such as *"I would like to learn how to sing"*, but cannot be used on its own in this way.

The sentence:

> **How to** determine if my roulette wins were due to luck or due to skill?

does not have any subject or verb which makes it incorrect.

The sentence:

> **How can I** determine if my roulette wins were due to luck or due to skill?

is fully formed, containing both the subject, **I**, and the modal verb **can**.

This is a common error that non-English speakers make frequently, and is a giveaway that the speaker is not yet fluent.

Unrelated to your question, the ending of your sentence

> "...due to luck or due to skill?"

is somewhat verbose, and a native speaker would likely say this as:

> "...due to luck or skill?"